# Re-connecting fails with NioSocketConnector

Tags: java, mina

```
ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(address);
future.addListener(new IoFutureListener<ConnectFuture>() {
    @Override
    ublic void operationComplete(ConnectFuture future) {
    try
    {
        if (future.isConnected())
```

when I connect using the following code to a server it works fine and `isConnected` returns me `TRUE`. But when server crash and comes up I try it again. Then its not working. Then I need to restart the client as well. Any idea why?

Comment: please, show how it tries it again

Comment: I check "connector.isActive()", every few minutes and if it is not active then I call the code above again.

Comment: Try `close`, `destroy` or `dispose` on that connector before new connection. And you can try to create new instance of connector.

Comment: Did you try all combinations?

Comment: only option is dispose(). I tired it and also created a new connector

Comment: What else do you do in method `operationComplete()`? Maybe the method doesn't return and blocks the `IoConnector`, so it cannot be closed.